# Let $x,y \in \mathbb C^n$ , where $n>1$ ; then does there exist symmetric $A \in M_n(\mathbb C) $ such that $Ax=y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $x,y \in \mathbb C^n$ , where $n>1$ ; then does there exist $A \in M_n(\mathbb C) $ such that $Ax=y$ ? Can we find such a symmetric matrix $A$ ?

Comment: For sure such a matrix $A$ exists (provided $x\neq 0$, as pointed out by @barto), now I'm not sure if it can be chosen to be symmetric.

Comment: You may want to clarify whether you want a complex symmetric $A$ (for which $A=A^T$) or a Hermitian $A$ (for which $A=A^\ast=\left(\bar{A}\right)^T$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course we must assume $x \ne 0$.

EDIT: Assuming you really do mean symmetric rather than Hermitian:

If $y^T x \ne 0$ (where ${}^T$ is transpose) then $A = (y^T x)^{-1} y y^T$ will do.

If
$y^T x = 0$, take $z$ such that $z^T x \ne 0$, and 
$A = (z^T x)^{-1} (y z^T + z y^T)$.

If you meant $A$ should be Hermitian, then as user1551 remarks you need to assume $y^H x$ is real (where ${}^H$ is Hermitian transpose).
Then if $y^H x \ne 0$, take $A = (y^H x)^{-1} y y^H$; if 
$y^H x = 0$, take $A = (x^H x)^{-1} (x y^H + y x^H)$.

Comment: You also want that $y^Hx$ is real, otherwise $A$ does not exist.

Comment: @ Robert Israel : Could you please demonstrate that this matrices that you have produced , indeed works ? and also that they are symmetric ..

Comment: That it works: Just write down $A x$ and use the associative law.  That they are symmetric: just write down $A^T$ and use $(ab)^T = b^T a^T$ and $(a^T)^T = a$.